# Change style of single elements in Primefaces datatable with javascript?

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I am trying to change the color of some p:progressBar elements inside a PrimeFaces Datatable

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="table" value="#{bean.data}">
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{data.chapter}"/>
         </p:column>
         <p:column>
             <p:progressBar id="progress" value="#{bean.pb[data.id]}"/>
          </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

using the following Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                for (i = 0; i &lt; 7; i++) {
                    var pb = PF('widget_form_table_' + i + '_progress');
                    var value = pb.getValue();
                    var rating = value / 25;

                    if (rating === 1) {
                        $(".ui-progressbar-value").css("background", "Tomato");
                    } else if (rating === 2) {
                        $(".ui-progressbar-value").css("background", "Orange");
                    } else if (rating === 3) {
                        $(".ui-progressbar-value").css("background", "DodgerBlue");
                    } else if (rating === 4) {
                        $(".ui-progressbar-value").css("background", "MediumSeaGreen");
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
```

This gets the right values, but of course it changes the color of all the progress bars in the datatable. However I would like to change every element separately. I know you can change a single element by assigning a custom styleClass and putting this in the js selector,

```
$(".myStyle .ui-progressbar-value")
```

but I don't understand how to do this for elements inside a datatable, without them all having the same styleClass.
I also tried using

```
$("#form_table_" + i "_progress .ui-progressbar-value")
```

but this doesn't change the color at all. I'm using PrimeFaces 6.2.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can give each progressbar a specific styleClass based on the row index of the datatable via the varStatus and use that.

Comment: or use the [`:nth-child()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) on the table row

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I did implement a solution with the :nth-child() selector.